# why role base parent of two child component have different state if update in one of these child component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to know I have one parent component and two child components and these child components are separated according to the user role. I have passed the parent state in these child components. In the beginning, both child components have the same state value, but if I update the state value in one child component, it will not update the state value in another component why.
Here is an example code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Demo1 from "./Demo1";
import Demo2 from "./Demo2";

const Demo = () => {
 
  const [staVal, setStaVal] = useState("hi");

  console.log(staVal);
  
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"));

  return (
    <div>
      {user.role === "user" ? (
        <Demo1 staVal={staVal} handler={() => setStaVal("google")} />
      ) : (
        <Demo2 staVal={staVal} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Demo1 component:

import React from "react";

```
const Demo1 = ({ staVal, setStaVal, handler }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>demo1:{staVal}</div>
      <button onClick={handler}>clik</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Demo1;
```

Demo 2 component:

```
import React from "react";

const Demo2 = ({ staVal }) => {
  return <div>demo2:{staVal}</div>;
};

export default Demo2;
```

Comment: Can you past the code in description from the images?

Comment: Ok I have update the code. Please check provide me answer

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `localStorage` is a **side effect**.
Side effects cannot be called from the `render` method (for Class components) or the top level (function components).

In your code, access the localStorage inside `useEffect(()=>{}, [])` or
inside `componentDidMount` if you want to make it a class component.

Answer (score 0):

> use the useEffect to get the item from the local storage.

```
const [user,setUser]=useState(null);
useEffect(()=>{
  const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"));
  setUser(currentUser)
 },[])

 return (
<div>
  {user.role === "user" ? (
    <Demo1 staVal={staVal} handler={() => setStaVal("google")} />
  ) : (
    <Demo2 staVal={staVal} />
  )}
</div>
```

);
};